# android/java: use something else rather then ObjectInputStream to load an object

Tags: java, android, performance, load, objectinputstream

I have a bunch of objects stored in several files that I need to load into memory at the start of my app, this is how I do it:

```
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    Object result = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(inFile);
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        result = ois.readObject();
        //and then do something with result
```

The problem is, when I try to load an object(`HashMap<Integer, int[]>`) of size more than 500k, it takes forever on my phone. I am not sure if it is the problem of ObjectInputStream, if it is, are there any other faster ways to store and retrieve objects from a file? The faster the better, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/overview.html) or Android's native serialization: [Parcel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html).

**update:**

Why are you storing so many objects in a file and loading them all at the same time into memory? As you found out it takes forever and uses a lot of memory. Is there any particular reason you need this?

You should be using a database - it lets you selectivelly query data and only load objects that you need at particular time.

Comment: I have looked at Parcel, it appears that it is not suitable for storing in a file though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping your FileInputStream into a BufferedInputStream? It minimizes expensive interaction with the underlying stream.

```
...
ois = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(fis));
...
```